# Rss parsing issue (XML)

Tags: android

This is my RSS ,XML file from which i want to extract the data. I have done my whole work with the SAX parser every thing works fine. But I parsed the whole RSS file and getting the each single element data like .

But my problem is i'm getting the whole file  element data but i want only  elements which are in  only.

```
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>RSS Feed</title>
<link>http://www.xyz.com</link>
<description>Calendar RSS Feeds</description>
<language>en-us</language>
<ttl>60</ttl>
<item>
<title>
title 1
</title>
<description>description 1</description>
<link>
http://www.xyz.com
</link>
<guid isPermaLink="false">6027@http://www.xyz.com</guid>
</item>
<item>
<title>
title 2
</title>
<description>description 2</description>
<link>
http://www.xyz.com
</link>
<guid isPermaLink="false">5554@http://www.xyz.com</guid>
</item>
<item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

I had tried all the combinations to set this i'll show my code here i made startElement and 
endElement methods:-

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        current = true;

        if (localName.equals("channel"))
        {
            itemList = new ItemList();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        current = false;

        if(localName.equals("title"))
        {
            itemList.setTitle(currentValue);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(current)
        {
            currentValue = new String(ch, start, length);
            current=false;
        }
    }
```

Any one please suggest me how can i only retrive the  elements which are in under  elements only.

I also tried this but this gives me error

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        current = true;

        if (localName.equals("channel"))
        {
            if (localName.equals("item"))
            {
            itemList = new ItemList();
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it wil help....

```
url = new URL("http://www.abcd.com/rss.xml");//.......
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    if(conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
          DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
          DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
          Document doc;
          doc = db.parse(url.openStream());
          doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
          NodeList itemLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");



          Array.Description = new String[itemLst.getLength()];//........
          Array.Title = new String[itemLst.getLength()];
          Array.image = new String[itemLst.getLength()];
          Array.Date = new String[itemLst.getLength()];

          for(int i=0; i < itemLst.getLength(); i++){

                Node item = itemLst.item(i);
                if(item.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                      Element ielem = (Element)item;
                      NodeList title = ielem.getElementsByTagName("title");
                      NodeList date = ielem.getElementsByTagName("pubDate");

                      NodeList description = ielem.getElementsByTagName("description");

                    ////.........
                      Array.Title[i] = title.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                      Array.Description[i] = description.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                      Array.Date[i] = date.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
```

Comment: I already tried this DocumentBuilder i got result from this but in this i don't know how to implement StringBuffer because i don't get the full data in DocumentBuider. Can you suggest me how to implement StringBuffer with DocumentBuilder.Thanks...

Comment: k...I have built an RSS reader.I will post my whole file I used for parsing..Just check it...

Answer (score 0):

```
public class headlinesparser {


public static void parse(){
URL url;
try {
    url = new URL("http://www.abcd.com/taxonomy/term/19/rss.xml");//.......
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    if(conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
          DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
          DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
          Document doc;
          doc = db.parse(url.openStream());
          doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
          NodeList itemLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");



          Headlines.Description = new String[itemLst.getLength()];//........
          Headlines.Title = new String[itemLst.getLength()];
          Headlines.image = new String[itemLst.getLength()];
          Headlines.Date = new String[itemLst.getLength()];

          for(int i=0; i < itemLst.getLength(); i++){

                Node item = itemLst.item(i);
                if(item.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                      Element ielem = (Element)item;
                      NodeList title = ielem.getElementsByTagName("title");
                      NodeList date = ielem.getElementsByTagName("pubDate");

                      NodeList description = ielem.getElementsByTagName("description");

                    ////.........
                      Headlines.Title[i] = title.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                      Headlines.Description[i] = description.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                      Headlines.Date[i] = date.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();

                    if (Headlines.Description[i].contains("<img ")){

                    String img  = Headlines.Description[i].substring(Headlines.Description[i].indexOf("<img "));
                    String cleanUp = img.substring(0, img.indexOf(">")+1);
                    img = img.substring(img.indexOf("src=") + 5);
                    int indexOf = img.indexOf("'");
                    if (indexOf==-1){
                        indexOf = img.indexOf("\"");
                    }
                    img = img.substring(0, indexOf);

                    //setImgLink(img);

                    Headlines.image[i]=img;

                      }




                }

          }

    }

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (DOMException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SAXException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}


}
```